# Using search to solve the 15-puzzle

Tags: java, puzzle

I'm trying to write a 4 x 4 grid using vertical bars and underscore. I have a class for the puzzle, but i want to know what fields and methods i can use to represent and manipulate a configuration for the puzzle.

Reference: [Fifteen puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifteen_puzzle)

Comment: Could you be a little more vague?  People can almost tell what you're asking for here.

Comment: It's really unclear what you want to know.

Comment: @Paul - I disagree.  I think it is sufficiently vague.  I haven't a clue what he wants to known :-).

Comment: The edit replaced "15 puzzle" with puzzle. The 15 puzzle is at least listed on wikipedia. While it was not good to use a tag for it, at least place it in the question! Can someone readd the 15 puzzle to the question?

Comment: @skaffman is there a way to downvote edits, if I knew how I would downvote this. Removing information instead of moving it into the question does not add any value!

Comment: I'm giving this another chance.  The comments about the question being too vague started right after information was removed (rightly) from the tags, but not put back in to the title or body.  I *think* there's enough information here for someone to answer, but I'll leave it alone if the community overrules me.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, you could give more information... however, consider an approach like this:

In your puzzle class, you may have a Value[][] member for storing the values. You could do something like this

```
public Value get(int x, int y) {
    return values[x][y];
}

public void set(int x, int y, Value v) {
    values[x][y] = v;
}
```